# Docker application to write to stdout and read from stdin

Tags: shell, python, docker

I am working on a task in which i am asked to do following thing.

```
docker run <arg> <image> writetostdout
```

This should write the tar file present in a director passed in one arg to stdout and exit

```
docker run -p 80:80 <arg> <imagge> readfromstdin
```

This should read the stdout and create file.

Can any one give some idea about this as how to do it? how can second command read from stdin? It is possible only if first command is piped to second or any other way? Any idea as how the second command can be implemented? Please guide me if its not a correct place to ask this question.